# How I could make a temperature sweep in comsol?

Tags: temperature, comsol

I make a structure using Comsol then I want to make this structure subjected to a temperature variation ( T(begain)=25C then a temperature ramp (100 C/min) till T=250C and it lasts for 30 min then another temperature ramp (-100 C/min) till T=25C ).How could I make these temperature sweep?

Comment: Could you have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550076/simulation-of-effect-of-heated-resistance-on-temperature-distribution-in-laminar?noredirect=1#comment74163876_43550076

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function (e.g foo) that follows exactly your desired temperature with time profile. Then in the place where you specify your temperature (whether it is a boundary condition or domain condition) you insert foo(t), t being COMSOL's exclusive variable name for time.

You can do that for other variables too, space for instance. The easiest way to define foo is through the 1D interpolation option. Unfortunately, I do not currently have a COMSOL license to check it but I think you can simply enter the time and temperature values in the 1D interpolation table, choose a name and the interpolant style and just use it in the later part of the program.

Answer (score 0):

I'am simulating magnetic fields in time domain with moving coils. Time dependent solver is needed for the movement and for temperature ramps as well. I think that you can use something like this, T=T_start+rate_of_change*t. The t variable is available with the time dependent solver and you can simply write the equation I mentioned. However, I think that you need to use time dependent solver three times, one for ramp up second for the constant temperature and third for the ramp down. Set the times for time dependent solvers so that you can made the desired temperatures.

```
First t=0s->(225/100*60)135s
second t=135s->(135+30*60)1935s
and last one t=1935s->(1935+135)2070s
```

You might also need to use compile solutions steps as well to add these three solutions together. I can try to do this tomorrow and check it.

Hope that this helped a bit